# Автоматизация убирания переносов openoffice

Tags: open-office

Не уверен что это совсем по данной теме но вдруг кто чего подскажет. Есть данные в OpenOffice Calc
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

C вот таким багом. Можно ли как то в open office calc автоматизировать проверку строки и если есть подобный перенос - собрать строку без переноса?

Comment: если вы каким-нить языком программирования владеете, то может оказаться проще сохранить в csv , починить и загрузить обратно

Comment: К сожалению csv здесь не очень подходит. Ну или я не могу придумать алгорим). Дело в том что данные строки парсятся как например 3 элемента а потом пустота. Итого массив по большей части из пустоты. И если объеденить эти массивы - получается не корректный массив ( сбит порядок данных ).